# How to say nothing is selected by using curselection in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a code that uses `Listbox.curselection()`:

```
self.index = int(self._Listbox.curselection()[0])
```

I would like to raise an error window when nothing is selected in the Listbox.

Any feedback would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% sure what the problem is.  If there are no items selected, the `self._Listbox.curselection()` should return an emtpy list.  Since you then grab index 0, it should throw an `IndexError`.

Demo Code:

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()

listbox = Listbox(master)
listbox.pack()

listbox.insert(END, "a list entry")

for item in ["one", "two", "three", "four"]:
    listbox.insert(END, item)

def callback():
    items = map(int, listbox.curselection())
    if(len(items) == 0):
        print "No items"
    else:
        print items

button = Button(master,text="press",command=callback)
button.pack()
mainloop()
```

Based on the behavior of the code above (nothing selected returns an empty list), your code *should* throw an IndexError when you don't have anything selected ... now you just need to handle the exception:

```
try:
    self.index = int(self._Listbox.curselection()[0])
except IndexError:
    tkMessageBox.showwarning("Oops","Need to select something")
```

Finally, I suppose I'll leave a [link to some documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-standard-dialogs.htm) on the standard Tkinter dialogs (`tkMessageBox` module)